# MySQL: grant a user privileges to access a schema from any computer

Tags: mysql

This question may have been asked many times but I can't find an answer that solves my problem.
I want to create a user that can connect to MySQL (5.5.35) on my box from any computer and have all privileges on the schema except GRANT.

So I started with:

```
$ mysql -u root -p
```

and then

```
create user 'dbuser'@'%' identified by 'password';
grant usage on *.* TO 'dbuser'@'%';
grant all on testdb to 'dbuser'@'%';
grant all on testdb.* to 'dbuser'@'%';
flush privileges;
quit
```

But to my surprise when I tried to connect to the database with:

```
$ mysql -u dbuser -p testdb
```

I get the following error message:

```
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'dbuser'@'localhost' 
(using password: YES)
```

and I did triple check the password. What am I doing wrong?

Cheers,
Johan

Comment: Whats the output of `select user, host from mysql.user;`? If you have multiple users with the same user name it can cause this problem.

Comment: The output is: mysql> select user, host from mysql.user;
+------------------+-----------+
| user             | host      |
+------------------+-----------+
| dbuser           | %         |
| root             | 127.0.0.1 |
| root             | ::1       |
|                  | lion      |
| root             | lion      |
|                  | localhost |
| debian-sys-maint | localhost |
| root             | localhost |
+------------------+-----------+
8 rows in set (0.00 sec)

Answer (score 0):

The clue here is the `@localhost` in the error message.

excerpt from MySQL documentation:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/connecting.html

On Unix, MySQL programs treat the host name **`localhost`** specially, in a way that is likely different from what you expect compared to other network-based programs. For connections to localhost, MySQL programs attempt to connect to the local server by using a Unix socket file. This occurs even if a --port or -P option is given to specify a port number. To ensure that the client makes a TCP/IP connection to the local server, use --host or -h to specify a host name value of 127.0.0.1, or the IP address or name of the local server. You can also specify the connection protocol explicitly, even for localhost, by using the --protocol=TCP option.

---

The fix is either to create user `'dbuser'@'localhost'` and grant privileges,

or to force connection through TCP/IP stack, e.g:

```
mysql -h 127.0.0.1 -u dbuser -p testdb
      ^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: Your suggestion will not work for me as I want to be able to connect to the database from any computer. I think I actually found a solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10299148/mysql-error-1045-28000-access-denied-for-user-billlocalhost-using-passw?rq=1. I too had anonymous users so after I deleted them everything works.